# Worst case runtime of random quicksort if you keep randomly choosing a pivot and partitioning until you find a good pivot

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, quicksort

If you changed the random quicksort algorithm to repeatedly randomly pick a pivot and run partition until it finds a "good" pivot what would be the worst case cost of the algorithm? If we kept track of the pivots used so far so that we never use the same one twice for the same array.

Comment: Randomly picking a pivot until you find a good one is O(n^2) worst case, even if you keep track of the pivots used so far. So the method proposed in the question will not improve the running time of quicksort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worst case, the random pivot always is the maximum or minimum possible value, in which case the runtime is O(n^2).
For a more detailed analysis, look [here](http://www.facweb.iitkgp.ac.in/%7Esourav/Lecture-04.pdf).
The expected value of the runtime is still O(n * log n) though.